# Can't locate API module structure `php7_module' in file /usr/webconfig/modules/libphp7.so

Tags: php, apache

I have existing **PHP 5.3.3**(Zend Engine v2.3.0) with Apache/2.4.7(**webconfig**). I wanted to update PHP version to **PHP-7.3.12**.
After building the source code I tried to update the **httpd.conf** by replacing existing   line

`LoadModule php5_module ./modules/libphp5.so`
to
`LoadModule php7_module ./modules/libphp7.so`

when trying to start **webconfig** it showing below error.
`$ service webconfig stop`
`Graceful stopping webconfig: httpd: Syntax error on line 228 of /usr/webconfig/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /usr/webconfig/conf/httpd.d/server_php.conf: Can't locate API module structure 'php7_module' in file /usr/webconfig/modules/libphp7.so: /usr/webconfig/modules/libphp7.so: undefined symbol: php7_module`

Comment: Very similar problem here. Any tips?